# SEC_TO_TIME function in mysql is calculating for only one condition in group by

Tags: mysql

I have a duration column which contains values in seconds .Now as per my need i have to show it into SEC_TO_TIME.

```
SELECT wwid,
round(SUM(CASE toc WHEN 'LOCAL' THEN callcost ELSE 0 END),2) AS LOCALPRICE, 
round(SUM(CASE toc WHEN 'STD' THEN callcost ELSE 0 END),2) AS STDPRICE, 
round(SUM(CASE toc WHEN 'ISD' THEN callcost ELSE 0 END),2) AS ISDPRICE,
round(SUM(CASE toc WHEN 'INCOMING' THEN callcost ELSE 0 END),2) AS INCOMINGPRICE, 
count(case when toc = 'LOCAL' then 1 end) as LOCALCALLS, 
count(case when toc = 'STD' then 1 end) as STDCALLS, 
count(case when toc = 'ISD' then 1 end) as ISDCALLS, 
count(case when toc = 'INCOMING' then 1 end) as INCOMCALLS,
SEC_TO_TIME(CASE toc WHEN 'LOCAL' THEN sum(duration) ELSE 0 END)AS LOCALDUR, 
SEC_TO_TIME(CASE toc WHEN 'STD' THEN sum(duration) ELSE 0 END)AS STDDUR, 
SEC_TO_TIME(CASE toc WHEN 'ISD' THEN sum(duration) ELSE 0 END)AS ISDDUR, 
SEC_TO_TIME(CASE toc WHEN 'INCOMING' THEN sum(duration) ELSE 0 END)AS INCOMDUR,
count(destination) as TOTALCALLS,
SEC_TO_TIME(sum(duration))as TOTALDUR,
round(sum(callcost),2)as TOTALPRICE 
FROM processeddata_table 
WHERE calldate between '2010-10-01' and '2013-10-01'  
group by wwid  
LIMIT 0 , 50
```

Here for every WWID we need to get the duration in the form of  SEC_TO_TIME  but for every wwid duration is coming for only one calltype let it be either LOCAL,STD,ISD etc wheras it is there for others also

Any help will be highly appreciated..

Thanks in advance..

Comment: This seems to be about a single column value. Why post that big (unformatted) query?

Comment: @juergend sorry sir i am novice in this forum doesnot know to post query ..please guide ..

Comment: use the code button `{}` in the question editor to format code. Mark the code and click the button.

Comment: @juergend please sir give me some suggestion .is using group by wwid is showing the last record..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of this...

```
SEC_TO_TIME(CASE toc WHEN 'STD' THEN sum(duration) ELSE 0 END)AS STDDUR
```

...what you probably intended is this...

```
SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(CASE toc WHEN 'STD' THEN duration ELSE 0 END)) AS STDDUR
```

The SUM () aggregate function needs to apply no matter which CASE matches each row in the group.  This needs to be changed on all of the columns with a similar expressions.